# Adding dateCreated field to existing object

Tags: grails

I want to add a "dateCreated" field to an object that is already exiting, and the corresponding table already has several objects in it.  When the dateCreated timestamp column is added the timestamp is set to '0000-00-00 00:00:00', but I need to set it to the actual dateCreated value that I call when I am at the groovy/grails level.

Is there a way to populate the new column with the correct 'dateCreated' value?

Comment: You already have another column with the date? If no, how you will know the correct date?

Comment: I don't have it in a column, I misunderstood how "dateCreated" worked (I thought you didn't have to add it to the domain model).  Luckily I have the date captured in text in another column, so I guess I'll have to go with something like bschipp suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may possibly be able to do this by setting a default value for the dateCreated field in your domain class?

eg.

```
class ExistingDomainObject {
    Date dateCreated = someFunctionToCalculateCorrectDateCreated()
}
```

Comment: Well I really need to get that date into the existing database records (I want to use it for search and sort).

Comment: Oh, i understand now, would it be possible to do an iteration over all your domain objects in the grails bootstrap init closure so that if any objects don't have a date created you update and save them?

Comment: OK, after a little more research I realize that dateCreated is only saved if you have that added to your domain model (I don't) but luckily I have the date in text in another column, so I will be going with a solution like the one you proposed